# Play Framework frontend JS using Scala.js external dependencies

Tags: playframework, scala.js

I'm trying to share some scala code between a common library and my play framework web project using ScalaJS.

I've created the shared project using ScalaJS in a separate build (different folder, different build.sbt), including unit tests using uTest, and everything appears to be working as expected. I've cross compiled the library code to separate targets (shared_jvm and shared_js) and used SBT's publishLocal command. Everything is fine at this point.

I created a separate project in my play framework web application for my specific web application ScalaJS code in a web_js folder using this code:

```
lazy val web_js = (project in file("web_js")).settings(
  scalaVersion := "2.11.1",
  persistLauncher := true,
  persistLauncher in Test := false,
  unmanagedSourceDirectories in Compile := Seq((scalaSource in Compile).value),
  libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.scala-js" %%% "scalajs-dom" % "0.8.0",
    "be.doeraene" %%% "scalajs-jquery" % "0.8.0",
    "org.myorg" %%% "shared-js" % "0.1-SNAPSHOT"
  )).
  enablePlugins(ScalaJSPlugin, ScalaJSPlay)
```

The library is resolved without any issue by SBT. I'm able to compile and there are no errors, and I'm able to reference the shared library in my code.

In order to use my shared JS code, I extend JSApp and call an object in my shared library like so:

```
//Index.scala
import org.myorg.shared.SharedObject

object Index extends JSApp {
  def main(): Unit = {
    SharedObject.printSomething()
  }
}
```

However, when this is called after I load up my browser, I get an undefined error related to the object in my shared library:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

How can I load a dependent ScalaJS library into a page in my Play Framework project?

*Other notes:*

I'm unable to see my shared library code in the "sources" debugger view of chrome. I'm only able to see the Index.scala code snippet pasted above. This makes me believe that the shared library I'm referencing isn't actually being loaded by the browser, but I'm not sure if that's the way it works or not.

By the way, I have seen the [play-with-scalajs-example](https://github.com/vmunier/play-with-scalajs-example) project, and I'm using it to load the Index.scala entry point above using this snippet:

```
@playscalajs.html.scripts("/assets", projectName = "web_js")
```

But I haven't had any success using it to load a dependent library.

Comment: Do you see any warnings when you run `web_js/fastOptJS`? The fact that you do not see any sources might just be some relative path issue with the source maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I just misunderstood the javascript error and/or hadn't updated the generated javascript in some time.

It turns out I was depending on an external javascript resource (moment.js) which wasn't being loaded. When I load it manually by inserting the script tag into the page:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.9.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

It works as expected and calls my shared library. It's strange because I don't recall seeing my code in the generated fastopt.js script, but I must have missed it or had some configuration issue on my box previously.

I'm not sure why my embedded moment.js script isn't working, since it's part of the resources in one of my dependencies and I've included it in the jsDependencies settings like so:

```
jsDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.myorg" %%% "momentjs" % "0.1-SNAPSHOT" / "moment.js"
)
```

But I suppose that's a question for a new post if I can't figure it out.

Comment: If it's helpful to anyone, I just needed to add:

   skip in packageJSDependencies := false

to my play framework JS project SBT configuration. Then I could reference the dependency script in my HTML file by using:

   <script src="@routes.Assets.at("web_js-jsdeps.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

Where web_js is the name of my Scala JS project.